# Switching to Python 3.6 in Wing101

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wing-ide

I am running Windows 10 and have Python 3.6 installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)". I have Wing working when using Python 2.7, but when I try to switch to Python 3.6 (Edit > Configure Python) I get the following error message:

```
Trying to import netserver from C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101
5.0\bin\3.6\src\debug\tserver Unable to import findmodules Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101
5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 415, in FindNetServerModule
    import findmodules ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'findmodules' Trying to import netserver from C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver Unable to import findmodules Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 415, in FindNetServerModule
    import findmodules ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'findmodules' Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 632, in main
    netserver = FindNetServerModule(winghome, user_settings, tmp_log)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 451, in FindNetServerModule
    raise ImportError('Could not import netserver')

ImportError: Could not import netserver

wingdb.py: Error: Failed to start the debug server wingdb.py: Error: You may be running an unsupported version of Python wingdb.py: Python version = 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] wingdb.py: WINGHOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Wing IDE 101 5.0' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 632, in main
    netserver = FindNetServerModule(winghome, user_settings, tmp_log)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 451, in FindNetServerModule
    raise ImportError('Could not import netserver') ImportError: Could not import netserver

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\wingdb.py", line 643, in main
    sys.exit(-1) SystemExit: -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Wing 6 since Wing 5 does not support Python 3.6.  You can get it at http://wingware.com/downloads/wingide-101